# Google Play internal app sharing no longer works on any device

Tags: android, google-play, internal-app-sharing

At my company we use Google Play's [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en-GB) links to provide builds to QA. As of an hour or so ago, opening any link [now fails, showing this error inside Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpbY0.png):

> To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app.

- This happens on every device & OS tested, all of which previously handled links perfectly.
- We are not using opt-in testing, only 1 google account is whitelisted for the builds.
- The links are in the format `https://play.google.com/apps/test/xxxxx/xxxx-xxxx_xxxx`.
- Since it happened on all devices at the same time, I suspect it's a remote config switch.

Is there any known workaround?

*Note: None of [these suggested solutions](https://old.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/7lv04m/google_play_now_intercepts_all_links_to_the/) work, as they just let you open the URL in the browser. That doesn't help, as [the URL just provides a link to open it in the Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Jk0.png).*

Comment: I face the same issue for 2 hours, I believe it is a temporary error that we need to try again later or something is down on Google's side.

Comment: same here, even we are facing this issue since 4 hours

Comment: Is there a place to report this bug? I tried to look this on issuetracker without success.

Comment: Same problem here :/

Comment: 2022 and still stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by a temporary outage on Google's end. It resolved itself a few hours later.

Answer (score 0):

Try directly this if link is originated from an app for Android to handle:

market://details?id=<package_name>

Note: There's no domain and host.