# Uploading to Google Play Internal App Sharing no longer works, returns 500 error

Tags: google-play, internal-app-sharing

As part of our CI process, we automatically upload an app bundle to internal app sharing. This is done directly via a CURL call:

```
    HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --progress-bar \
    --request POST \
    --upload-file ${BUNDLE_LOCATION} \
  https://www.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/internalappsharing/${PACKAGE}/artifacts/bundle?uploadType=media)
```

This has worked for 8-9 months perfectly, but as of this morning we are receiving a 500 response (any IDs redacted):

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":500,
      "message":"Internal error encountered.",
      "status":"INTERNAL",
      "details":[
         {
            "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
            "detail":"[ORIGINAL ERROR] generic::internal: com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/GenerateService.GenerateAdHocSharingKeys, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED'/> DEADLINE_EXCEEDED;playappspublisher.appsigning/GenerateService.GenerateAdHocSharingKeys;Deadline=30.0s;StartTimeMs=1597913956916;tcp;Deadline(sec)=30.0;ResFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;Originator=play-console-publishingapi-esf;Tag=cloud_project_number[redacted]IncomingMethod/InternalAppSharingArtifactsService.UploadBundlecidc2;NoServerTime;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;ReqID=[redacted];GlobalID=[redacted];Server=[2002:a66:786:0:b029:14a:6e5c:6e1]:8101
    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: "
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Any ideas what might be causing it? We experienced [a different Internal App Sharing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342557/google-play-internal-app-sharing-no-longer-works-on-any-device) 10 days ago, not sure if related.

At first glance it looks like some kind of timeout between internal Google servers tlaking to each other via RPC.

Thanks!

**Update**: It briefly worked! However, as of 14:00 GMT a slightly more user friendly error is now returned (just the usual Google error page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> <meta charset=utf-8> <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"> <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title> <style> *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px} </style> <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a> <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins> <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but it just occurred again today. I'm currently getting the "Error 502 (Server Error)!!1" message when uploading to my internal test track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it resolved itself around 13:00-14:00 GMT.